# Adding text from MySQL DB into a form inside a ColorBox

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql

I am having some trouble adding a text from my MySQL database into a form (textfield) inside a ColorBox.

I have this script now:

```
<a href="#" class="bttn sgreen quote1">Quote</a>

    var postQuote[<?php echo 4id; ?>]=<?php echo $forum->bb_parse($forumPost['post_text']); ?>;
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $(".replyBox").colorbox({inline:true, top: 100, overlayClose:false, width:"35%",href:"#addReply"});
     });
```

And the ColorBox:

```
<div style="display:none;">
    <div id="addReply" style='padding:10px; background:#fff;'>
        <form method="post" action="#" class="mainForm">
            <label>Your Reply:</label><br /><br />
            <textarea rows="10" style="height:320px;width:400px" cols="20" id="bb" name="text"></textarea>
            <br />
            <div style="text-align:center;">
            <button type="submit" class="bttn sgreen" >Post Reply</button>
            </div>                                 
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I, when I press quote, add the "var postQuote" into the textfield and open the ColorBox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#bb").val(postQuote);
   $(".replyBox").colorbox({inline:true, top: 100, overlayClose:false,     width:"35%",href:"#addReply"});
});
```